# Unable to fetch <div> tag values in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The required value is present within the div tag:

```
<div class="search-page-text">
<span class="upc grey-text sml">Cost for 2: </span>
Rs. 350 
</div>
```

I am using the below code to fetch the value "Rs. 350":

```
soup.select('div.search-page-text'):
```

But in the output i get "None". Could you pls help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you only ever want the string that is the immediate text of the `<div>` tag and not the `<span>` child element, you could do this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="search-page-text">
<span class="upc grey-text sml">Cost for 2: </span>
Rs. 350 
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)

for div in soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "search-page-text" }):
    print ''.join(div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
    #print div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)[1].strip()
```

One of the lines returned by `div.find_all` is just a newline. That could be handled in a variety of ways. I chose to `join` and `strip` it rather than rely on the text being at a certain index (see commented line) in the resultant list.

**Python 3**

For python 3 the print line should be

```
print (''.join(div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip())
```

Comment: I am getting the below mentioned error when i try to run the code:

Comment: print (''.join(div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip())
                                                                    ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I checked the identation. It seems fine

Comment: Its because I'm using spaces and you're using tabs. You just need to change that one indented line from 4 spaces to a tab character.

Comment: I am getting Invalid syntax error at the apostrohe after print

Comment: print ''.join(div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Even when you run my example?

Comment: i am using Python 3.4. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yeah, i get the invalid syntax error when i use your code alone

Comment: Yep its because print needs to be a function call. I edited my answer.

Comment: Cool. Does it do what you wanted?

Comment: This works fine for the one tag that i provided as example. But when i use it for the entire page, i get the error : [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Comment: Can you add the offending element to the question?

Comment: I was using it in Sublime Text. It seems to have some issues with utf

Comment: Yep I saw there are plenty of questions about sublime text and that error. I have never used it before.

Comment: Cool if you want accept the answer that would rock. If not no worries.

Answer (score 2):

An element with both a sub-element and string content can be accessed using [`strippe_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<div class="search-page-text">
<span class="upc grey-text sml">Cost for 2: </span>
Rs. 350
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

for s in soup.select("div.search-page-text")[0].stripped_strings:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
Cost for 2:
Rs. 350
```

The problem is that this includes both the strong content of the `span` and the `div`. But if you know that the `div` *first* contains the `span` with text, you could get the intersting string as

```
list(soup.select("div.search-page-text")[0].stripped_strings)[1]
```

Comment: since the page has other div tags with "search-page-text" i am getting irrelevant values. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: can the span tag be leveraged?

Comment: I am getting just the Cost for 2: value

Comment: As you can see I am using the index `[0]` to access the *first* `div.search-page-text`. If there are more such elements, use a different index.